# Email sending from server outside of network

Tags: email, exim

I am building out a web solution for a client with an option to send emails of the sites content to others.  The site is hosted on our system, as well as an SMTP server just for this feature.  However, in order for our SMTP server to be active, there is an MX record pointing to us.  Problem is, there is an organizational server in the clients network that handles their emails.  Our web solution is trying to send out from the SMTP on our end and it's finding itself first when the client trys to send to internal employees, instead of finding the organizational server.  The client cannot give connections credentials for their server for security reasons.  I have tried a forward on our side, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: If email to their domain is processed by their server why do you have MX record pointing to your server?

Comment: Our hosting option is setup that way.

Comment: So, you have MX record pointing to your server for some domain but you need to forward all emails to this domain to different server? You may specify smarthost (server where all emails should go) for certain domain. In sendmail and sendmail-like systems use mailertable (https://www.puryear-it.com/specify-smarthost-per-domain-sendmail). Postifx: https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/postfix-relay-one-domain-to-smarthost-a-all-else-to-smarthost-b.62955/ .Exim: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/exim-smart-host-for-specific-domains-607390/ .Which MTA do you have?

Comment: PS:And please note that you do not need to have MX record to SEND emails. You need public static IP, you need DMARC, SPF, DKIM and 10/10 points in www.mail-tester.com , but not MX

Comment: user996142 is right.  Your solution is simply to correct the DNS zone's MX record to point to the right server.  Doing it any other way will just make everyone's job more complex.